# How to set Makefile default shell under Windows without modifying make file itself?

Tags: windows, shell, makefile

I have sh.exe in my PATH and Makefile uses it no matter what other enviroment variables are set. It ignores ComSpec, SHELL and MAKESHELL that point to cmd.exe. If I set `SHELL := cmd` inside make file, then Makefile uses it, but I would like the opposite: I want Makefile  to use cmd.exe by default unless another shell is specified. How do I do this?

Comment: Before we can answer this question we need to know what you mean by "another shell is specified".  In what way were you imagining that another shell would be specified?

Comment: @MadScientist by setting `SHELL := sh` in a make file. So if the shell is not specified (i. e. no `SHELL` variable set), then default shell is cmd, even if sh.exe is in PATH and is visible to Makefile.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to do that, short of modifying the source code for GNU make and recompiling.  The default shell to look for first is hardcoded in the source to be `sh.exe` and only if that is not found, will it look for something else.  However if you set the `SHELL` environment variable (on Windows) then make will use that value, according to the user's manual.  It's still not the default though.